# jquery switchClass transition - background-image

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-animate, css-transitions, toggleclass

I'm having some problems with the method switchClass.
I want to add/remove a css class (`newsHover`) when the mouse is hover the class `newsArea` with some transition.

I have the following code

```
$('.newsArea').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).switchClass('','newsHover',500, 'linear');
 }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).switchClass('newsHover','',500);
});
```

I think the methods are correct as you can see:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions and 
http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/

The newsHover class has a background-image:

```
.newsHover{        
        background-image: url("../../images/newsArea-hover.png"); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position:left top;
        width: 200px; height: 52px;            
      }
```

The image appears but without any transition. It appears after the 500 milliseconds.

I can accept any solution with css3 cross-browser.

Any tips here??

thanks

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell that I'm using the 1.7.2 jquery version; jquery.easing.1.3, and jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min (with all the components selected)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925994/jquery-ui-switchclass-method-is-not-working-properly

Comment: thanks. But the addClass() and removeClass methods I can't have any transition, right?? or am I forgetting something??

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, the behaviour you describe is exactly as expected. the `switchClass`  function simply changes properties it can't animate at the end of the 'transition'. `switchClass` doesn't support animating background images.

> Not all styles can be animated. For example, there is no way to
>   animate a background image. Any styles that cannot be animated will be
>   changed at the end of the animation.

From [http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/][1]

Answer (score -1):

Have an initial class in place to switch with -

```
$('.newsArea').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).switchClass('oldClass','newsHover', 500);
 }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).switchClass('newsHover','oldClass',500);
});
```

**Maybe** the image takes time to load after you have applied it?

So you could try..

```
.oldClass{
  background-image: url("../../images/newsArea-hover.png"); 
  background-size:0px;
}
.newsHover{        
   background-size: auto;     
}
```

Comment: The first block of code doesn't work. If you could analyze the source code from 2nd link I gave you can see something similar. About the second block I didn't tried but I guess that it would change the opacity of the text that is inside my .newsArea class. So it's not a solution. Thanks

Comment: @user794035: I suspected so. I removed the `opacity` bit for another reason I thought could be causing your image taking time to load?

Comment: Thanks anyway. In a meanwhile if you have any other idea feel free to share it.