# jQuery UI switchClass() not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, jquery-ui

I am developing an image gallery with photos sliding `left` and `right` on mouse `scroll up` and `scroll down` respectively.

The gallery with 5 photos looks like this:

http://www.games07.tk/Untitled.png

**Function:**

```
function scrollPhotosLeft()
{
       $(".photo0").switchClass("photo0","photo1",500);
       $(".photo1").switchClass("photo1","photo2",500);
       $(".photo2").switchClass("photo2","photo4",500);
       $(".photo3").switchClass("photo3","photo0",500);
       $(".photo4").switchClass("photo4","photo3",500);
}
function scrollPhotosRight()
{
        $(".photo0").switchClass("photo0","photo3",500);
        $(".photo1").switchClass("photo1","photo0",500);
        $(".photo2").switchClass("photo2","photo1",500);
        $(".photo3").switchClass("photo3","photo4",500);
        $(".photo4").switchClass("photo4","photo2",500);
}
```

**CSS:**

```css
.photo0{
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
.photo1{
   top: 40%;
   left: 30%;
}
.photo2{
   top: 30%;
   left: 10%;
}
.photo3{
   top: 40%;
   left: 70%;
}
.photo4{
   top: 30%;
   left:90%;
}
```

Scrolling down causes no problem but in some conditions scrolling down and suddenly scrolling up causes the photos to look like this:

http://www.games07.tk/Untitled2.png

Is there any way to overcome this problem or any other way to implement this?

I had noticed that after some combination of scrolling up and down the switchClass() is giving same class for images (got this from Google Chrome Inspect Element)

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers to see if it operates differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925994/jquery-ui-switchclass-method-is-not-working-properly ?

Comment: @AdamPlocher in firefox switchClass() is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switchClass` doesn't change the class until the animation finishes, so calling it again before half a second has elapsed will cause funny behaviour.

You should pre-select, store a current position, and use animate instead of swapping classes;

```
var p0 = $(".photo0");
var p1 = $(".photo1");
// etc
var i = 0;
var posn = [
    {x:50,y:50},
    {x:100,y:70},
    {x:150,y:80},
    {x:200,y:70},
    {x:250,y:50}
];
function movePhotos(){
    p0.animate( posn[i], 500 );
    p1.animate( posn[(i+1)%5], 500 );
    // etc
}
function scrollPhotosLeft(){
    i = (i + 1) % 5;
    movePhotos();
}
function scrollPhotosRight(){
    i = (i + 5 - 1) % 5;
    movePhotos();
}
```