# Jquery - addClass and removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to switch the class from an `i` tag. First I tried it by using Jquery UI's `switchClass` like this:

```
$( "#sidenavIcon" ).switchClass('fa-angle-double-right', 'fa-angle-double-left');
```

This was not working. I discovered that someone else also had a problem with `switchClass` and he was adviced to [use `removeClass` and `addClass` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943803/4684797), which worked for him.

However, for me it does not work, and I am confused now.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#sidenav").on("click", function() {
      $("#sidenavIcon").addClass('fa-angle-double-right').removeClass('fa-angle-double-left');
    });
  }
);
```

```css
#sidenav {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  position: relative;
}

#sidenav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidenavIconWrap {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#sidenavIcon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidenav">
  <div id="sidenavIconWrap">
    <i id=sidenavIcon" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

It was indeed because of the missing `"`. I trusted PhpStorm to find this and point it out... I learned: never trust your IDE, even if you have a expensive one.

[image]

Comment: SO, now it's working now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were missing a `"` in `<i id=sidenavIcon"`.  It worked after I changed that. If you wan tit to toggle, go ahead and switch both `addClass` and `removeClass` with `toggleClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#sidenav").on("click", function() {
      $("#sidenavIcon").toggleClass('fa-angle-double-right').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-left');
    });
  }
);
```

```css
#sidenav {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 10vw;
  position: relative;
}

#sidenav:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidenavIconWrap {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#sidenavIcon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidenav">
  <div id="sidenavIconWrap">
    <i id="sidenavIcon" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, PhpStorm was not pointing out that the `"` is missing as you can see in the screenshot, so I did not noticed it.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: @AlivetoDie  didn't get the indication that they wanted `toggleClass`. I updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You just missed one *double quote* in your **HTML**, please follow below:
You have writen `id=sidenavIcon"`, but you should write `id="sidenavIcon"`

```
<div id="sidenav">
    <div id="sidenavIconWrap">
        <i id="sidenavIcon" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add an opening " in

```
<i id=sidenavIcon">
```

you can check it like this :

```
document.getElementById("sidenavIcon")
```

returns null

```
document.getElementById("sidenavIcon\"")
```

returns your div element.

So currently youe Id is **sidenavIcon"**

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution it's work smoothly

replace `id=sidenavIcon"` with `id="sidenavIcon"`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidenav").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#sidenavIcon").hasClass("fa-angle-double-right")) {
            $("#sidenavIcon").removeClass('fa-angle-double-right').addClass('fa-angle-double-left');
        }
        else {
            $("#sidenavIcon").addClass('fa-angle-double-right').removeClass('fa-angle-double-left');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#sidenav {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 10vw;
    position: relative;
}
#sidenav:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#sidenavIconWrap {
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#sidenavIcon {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidenav">
 <div id="sidenavIconWrap">
  <i id="sidenavIcon" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:** use toggleClass(); instead of switchClass() or add or remove class.
**HTML:** Add the miss " before **id= sidenavIcon"**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#sidenav").on("click", function() {

  $("#sidenavIcon").toggleClass('fa-angle-double-right fa-angle-double-left');
});
  });
```

```css
#sidenav {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 10vw;
    position: relative;
}
#sidenav:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#sidenavIconWrap {
 font-size: 50px;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#sidenavIcon {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sidenav">
 <div id="sidenavIconWrap">
  <i id="sidenavIcon" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```